# Best program for Permutation nPr of large numbers

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math, permutation

I am new to programming and was stuck at the permutation part. I have code which works for combination of large numbers which is stored in matrix but i am not able to find what should i change in that to get the result.
I tried the recursive method for permutations but could not achieve fast results.

This is the code which i got for combination what should be the change in condition which i should do here to get permutations?

```
 void combination()
 {
   int i,j;
   for(i=0;i<100;i++)
   {
     nCr[i][0]=1;
     nCr[i][i]=1;
   }
   for(i=1;i<100;i++)
     for(j=1;j<100;j++)
        if (i!=j)
        {
          nCr[i][j] = (nCr[i-1][j] + nCr[i-1][j-1]);
        }
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to compute? My maths on this is a bit rusty but isn't it if you are looking for nCr that is `nCr[n][r]` where `n` and `r` are the values you are looking for.

Comment: if you could provide the exact definition of Permuation nPr of large numbers, to make it clear exactly what your program is trying to do.

Comment: I'll demote my answer to comment: in any case nPk(n,k) or nCk(n,k), the function is defined only for 0<=k<=n.

Answer (score 1):

A recurrence rule for permutations can be easily derived from the definition:

```
nPk = n*(n-1)*(n-2)* ... * (n-k+1) = n * (n-1)P(k-1)
```

Converted to code:

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
  nPr[i][0]=1;
}
for(i=1;i<100;i++)
  for(j=1;j<100;j++)
     if (i!=j)
     {
       nPr[i][j] = i * nPr[i-1][j-1];
     }
```

Note that the number of permutations grows fast and overflows the storage available for `int`: 13P11 for example is already out of range with signed 32bit integers.

Comment: @Aki, we are talking about permutations, not combinations. 13P11 is 3.113.510.400 > 2^31.

Answer (score 0):

well you can use the following pseudo-code for computing permutation and combination given that **mod** is always a very large prime number.

for permutation nPr

```
func permutation(r,n,mod):
    q=factorial(n) // you should precompute them and saved in an array for a better execution time  
    r=(factorial(r))%mod
    return (q*math.pow(r,mod-2))%mod
```

for combination nCr

```
func combination(r,n,mod):
    q=factorial(n)  
    r=(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r))%mod
    return (q*math.pow(r,mod-2))%mod
```

your should precompute factorials , for a decent execution time.

```
fact[100000]
fact[0]=fact[1]=1
func factorial_compute():
    for x from 2 to 100000:
        fact[x]=(x*fact[x-1])%mod
```

hence your factorial function will be

```
func factorial(x):
    return(fact[x])
```

for reference on mathematics for this : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularInverse.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I know where the problem raised
At the point where we multiply , there is the actual problem ,when numbers get multiplied and get bigger and bigger.

this code is tested and is giving the correct result.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define mod 72057594037927936   // 2^56  (17 digits)
// #define mod 18446744073709551616 // 2^64 (20 digits) Not supported

long long int prod_uint64(long long int x, long long int y)
{
    return x * y % mod;
}
int main()
{
   long long int n=14, s = 1;
   while (n != 1)
   {
      s = prod_uint64(s , n) ;
      n--;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to different questions and please don't recommend using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.